# How to find equidistance from 4 points

Tags: geometry

So, for instance if we have 4 friends at 4 different cities and they want to walk in a straight lines and meet with each of them covering the same distance, how would we calculate it?

For 2 people problem it is easy, find the midpoint of the line
For 3 people you can draw a circle that goes through each of the points and find the centre of it, however I dont know how to proceed. Can we run a circle through any arbitrary number of points? My intuition says no. It's just something that came into my mind the other day, and it won't let go, but I am really struggling to find the answer.

Comment: How do you plan on drawing a circle through 3 people if they are all on the same line? Are you sure we can always find some equidistance?

Comment: now that you said it, yeah I didn't think about it. So you are telling me that there is no general rule basically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rarely possible. For it to be possible, you would have to be able to draw a circle that touches all four points, and the midpoint of the circle would be the point equidistant. However, if you take a rhombus for example (that is not a square), there is no circle that touches all four vertices, so it is not possible.

Comment: Good answer. Just to add to this a little bit, if it is possible to find an equidistant point, the shape you get by connecting the four cities together is called a *cyclic quadrilateral*, so you can look that up for more information. In general, a quadrilateral is cyclic if and only if its opposite angles are supplementary.

Answer (score 0):

It will only be possible if 3 persons are at ends of a equlateral triangle and 4th person should be on centre of triangle at a depth of √2/3 *d  , where d is the distance of the side of the triangle forming.

Comment: Please use MathJax.  There's a chatroom for queries, so there's no need to post your email.

Comment: Ok bro sorry....i was just trying to help others 

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible if it's a triangle (The centre of in circle aka in-centre) or cyclic quadrilateral. But in some permutations of 4 points, It's impossible to find the point equidistant from all the 4 points.

As per context, They are 4 persons. So, Only if the quadrilateral we gain after connecting their places is cyclic, There'll be a point equidistant from other 4 points